# Text Input not showing like Text area in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am not getting Text Area Place Holder getting in Center, but i want Top on PlaceHolder side like below as shown image .could you please suggest how to design based
[image]

Here is Code:

```
textInput: {
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        height: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 60 : 80,
        fontSize: 16,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        marginHorizontal: 15,
        padding: 10,
        marginTop: 8
    },
<TextInput
        placeholder="Comment  Here"
        blurOnSubmit={false}
        returnKeyType={"go"}
        style={styles.textInput}
        multiline={true}
        numberOfLines={20}
        underlineColorAndroid={"transparent"}
        autoCapitalize={"none"}
        autoCorrect={false}
        onChangeText={this.handleChange.bind(
            this,
            "comment"
        )}
        ref={input => {
            this.inputs["four"] = input;
        }}
        onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.submitOurView_Method();
        }}
        value={this.state.contactInfo_View.comment}
/>
```

Comment: **I am not getting Text Area Place Holder getting in Center**, can you show how it looks like as of now?

Comment: depending upon height, give paddingBottom that placeholder text will move upper

Answer (score 7):

This is my code.

```
<TextInput
   multiline={true}
   numberOfLines={12}
   textAlignVertical = "top"/>
```

**textAlignVertical** props is supported only android platform

Comment: this does not work in iOS